# How can you remove only the red characters from a complex PDF document?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a complex PDF document (to read it I used the library tessract), I would like to read only the red characters from this file.
How can I do it. My code Should be write in python.

I want to read abnormal blood tests from a blood text file

Comment: Tesseract is an OCR engine and as such unable to recognize text colors. Your only hope is  the original PDF page. And in that case you need a python package that can recognize the text color and selectively remove characters. PyMuPDF is such a package. **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: Either share an example PDF page here or join our public [PyMuPDF Discord](https://discord.gg/63t35Smg) channel.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, if you would use the package PyMuPDF. In my opinion, tesseract is not useful for your problem.

This is just a simple solution. You should define the color, you are looking for. Maybe you can find out the type of red manually. Furthermore, I could recommend to use a dictionary or data frame, if you have a lot of text and don't want to save the red text into a list.

```
# module from library pymupdf
import fitz

# load pdf
doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")

# define variable as placeholder for the desired red text
red_text = list()
# define the color in rgb hex, you are looking for
red_hex = "ff0000"
# convert hex to decimal
red_decimal = int("ff0000", 16)

# scan pdf
for page in doc:
    blocks = page.get_text("dict", flags=11)["blocks"]
    for b in blocks:  # iterate through the text blocks
        for l in b["lines"]:  # iterate through the text lines
            for s in l["spans"]:  # iterate through the text spans
                if s['color'] == red_decimal:
                    red_text.append(s['text'])

# show result
print(red_text)
```

I hope this could help. Please feel free to ask for any further help.